Import python packages astropy occur issues, how can i handle it?
My Python script is:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from fil_finder import FilFinder2D
from astropy import units

skeleton = cv2.imread("./zhang.png", 0)
fil = FilFinder2D(skeleton, distance=250 * units.pc, mask=skeleton)
fil.preprocess_image(flatten_percent=85)
fil.create_mask(border_masking=True, verbose=False,use_existing_mask=True)
fil.medskel(verbose=False)
fil.analyze_skeletons(branch_thresh=40* units.pix, skel_thresh=10 * units.pix, prune_criteria='length')
plt.imshow(fil.skeleton, cmap='gray')
plt.contour(fil.skeleton_longpath, colors='r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

my images of follow:

occurred bug is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\object_oriented\Image_Process_Scikit_Image\找出最长的裂缝From_Stackoverflow.py", line 13, in <module>
from fil_finder import FilFinder2D
    File "E:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\fil_finder\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from ._astropy_init import *
    File "E:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\fil_finder\_astropy_init.py", line 21, in <module>
from astropy.config.configuration import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'update_default_config' from 'astropy.config.configuration' (E:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\astropy\config\configuration.py)

Name: astropy
Version: 6.1.2
Name: fil-finder
Version: 1.7.2
python version is:3.10
I want to handle the script bug and make the crack branches are displayed in different colors；
looks like this, then find the intersection point, thanks a lot~


It's a problem with fil_finder package.
If you want a quick and dirty solution until they fix this issue, just go to this file E:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\fil_finder\_astropy_init.py and remove the line 22.
Or you can downgrade your astropy package to a version lower than 6, since the update_default_config was removed on this version.
Then you can continue coding your script:


The bug has been fixed, but how can I draw a different color for each branch?

Abukeram, you should ask a new question for that.
